# Can we add an extra index on _key column in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I have a requirement which requires to do range search on _key column. But in one of the blog of arangodb, they have mentioned that _key column can not be used for range queries and sort operations. So in this case what can we do? Can we add skiplist index on _key column?

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I have provided _key column as auto incremental attribute. So I want to search those documents which has _key value between 15 to 100 or 1000 to 4000  like that.

Comment: What storage engine are you employing?

Comment: I am using RocksDB as a storage engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `_key` attribute for searching ranges in the current version of ArangoDB (3.4.x). The primary index is not considered as sorted, even though in RocksDB the index is sorted. This will [change in v3.5.0](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/7720) (it is already implemented in the `devel` branch).

Adding a `skiplist` index to the collection over the `_key` attribute will have no effect.

The only way of managing indexed ranges in your collections is by holding a separate field, which is indexed accordingly to allow for range searches.

Comment: The feature to treat the primary index as sorted got implemented in the development branch and will become available with v3.5.0. Sorting and filtering will be possible on the `_key` attribute utilizing the index.